# distribution of sum of double exponential random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-function, convolution, gamma-distribution

I want to find out whether there is a concise expression (i.e. not a convolution) for the distribution of a random variable A which is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. rv's $B_i$, which are themselves double exponentially distributed with density $f_B(x) = 1_{x>0} \, p \, \eta^+ e^{-\eta^+ x} + 1_{x<0} \, q \, \eta^- e^{\eta^- x}$ , where $p+q = 1, p \ge 0, q \ge 0, \eta^+ > 0, \eta^- > 0$.

One route of thought went the way from the distribution of a sum of exponential rv's $C_i$ (with density $f_C(x) = 1_{x>0} \, \eta \, e^{-\eta x}, \, \eta > 0$) being a gamma distribution; so - is there anything similar?

Comment: I assume $\eta^+<0$ is a typo?

Comment: The answer is probably no, if you want an exact result.  We could find a good approximation, if that is enough ...

Comment: Yes thanks, typo corrected.

Comment: Related:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6887/formula-for-the-nth-convolution-of-a-laplace-random-variable

Comment: See:  Gallo, F. (1979). On the Laplace first law: Sample distribution of the sum of values
and the sum of absolute values of the errors; distribution of the related T ,
Statistics, 39, 443-454.   (If you can find it ...)

Comment: thanks, I could not find this article. I managed to find a closed-form expression for $p=q=1/2$ and $\eta^+ = \eta^-$, but not yet for arbitrary $\eta^+, \eta^-$; maybe, along the lines of the difference of two gamma distributed variables, there is a way to find the distribution of the latter with $p=q$, not sure, however...

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen: ok, I couldn't find any closed-form expression; the major hurdle is the characteristic function of the density, even if $p=q=1/2$. I will post a separate question on this. What would be a good approximation?